# Parse nested JSON in PySpark and convert to csv

Tags: json, apache-spark, pyspark

I am new to Spark and want to convert a nested JSON into CSV. Sample JSON:

```
{"key1": {"key11": "value11","key12": "value12"},  "key2": "value2"}
```

Following some bread crumbs on Stackoverflow, I am reading the json as:

```
mySchema = StructType([StructField('key1.key11', StringType(), True), StructField('key1.key12', StringType(), True), StructField('key2', StringType(), True)])
initialDF = spark.read.schema(mySchema).json(inputFile)
```

but this reads null values for key1.key11 and key1.key12 as shown below:

[image]

How do I get the real values here? Also, my json has 3 levels of nesting.
My goal is to be able to write the JSON to a CSV file with Key1.Key11, etc as column names, like below:

```
initialDF.write.option("header","true").csv("/tmp/output.csv")
```

Is there anything else I need to keep in mind?

**UPDATE**:
I updated the schema to:

```
mySchema1 = StructType([StructField('key1', StructType([StructField('key11', StringType(), True), StructField('key12', StringType(), True)]), True), StructField('key2', StringType(), True)])
```

So that Spark reads Key1 as a struct. Then I am able to retrieve the two fields in that struct using *Select* as:

```
newDF = initialDF.select("key1.key11", "key1.key12", "key2")
```

While this method seems to be working, it will not be a good solution if the json grows too big (like in my case).

Comment: Specify the schema corresponding to the structure of the json. You don't have to flatten it  : 
```partialSchema = StructType([StructField("key11", StringType(), nullable=True)
                           , StructField("key12", StringType(), nullable=True)
                        ])

actualSchema = StructType([StructField("key1", partialSchema, nullable=True)
                           , StructField("key2", StringType(), nullable=True)
                        ])```

Answer (score 0):

Spark will infer the schema for you automatically if you read a json file. Simply doing `spark.read.json(inputFile)` will work without the need to specify a schema manually.

```
>>> spark.read.json('test.json').show()
+------------------+------+
|              key1|  key2|
+------------------+------+
|[value11, value12]|value2|
+------------------+------+

>>> spark.read.json('test.json').printSchema()
root
 |-- key1: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- key11: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- key12: string (nullable = true)
 |-- key2: string (nullable = true)
```